# Showing Loading Bar lib

Tags: android

Hi there I am trying to use this lib into my app
https://github.com/jlmd/AnimatedCircleLoadingView
I want it to on top of that layout, can someone please show me ho it is done? 
I trying adding it but it either covered the whole screen or it would occupy a part of layout completly
layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/postBg"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newStatusHeader"
        style="@style/newStatusHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postOwnerImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerInfoContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/postsItemMargin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postOwnerName"
                style="@style/postOwnerName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postPrivacy"
                style="@style/postPublishDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/publicPrivacy"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#E9E9E9"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newStatusBody"
        style="@style/newStatusBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.github.jlmd.animatedcircleloadingview.AnimatedCircleLoadingView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/circle_loading_view"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:mainColor="@color/primaryColor"
                app:secondaryColor="@color/primaryColorDark"
                android:layout_gravity="top" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/statusEdittext"
            style="@style/statusEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="@string/urStatus"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/placePreviewLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/placeValuePreview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Rue Ibn ElArabi, Agadir 80000, Morocco"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_high_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/removePlace"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="X"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/urlPreviewLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_link_black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/urlValuePreview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="https://www.atouchlab.com"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_high_light"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/removeLink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="X"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#E9E9E9"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newStatusFooter"
        style="@style/newStatusFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addPhoto"
                style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_camera_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addPlace"
                style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_place_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addLink"
                style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_insert_link_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/changePrivacy"
                style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_privacy_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendStatus"
            style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_publish_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

lib layout

```
<com.github.jlmd.animatedcircleloadingview.AnimatedCircleLoadingView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/circle_loading_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:mainColor="@color/main_color"
    app:secondaryColor="@color/secondary_color"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved using an relative layout that wraps the view where you want the LoadingView to be on top of, ex:

```
    <RelativeLayout>

   <com.github.jlmd.animatedcircleloadingview.AnimatedCircleLoadingView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/circle_loading_view"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:mainColor="@color/primaryColor"
                app:secondaryColor="@color/primaryColorDark"
                />
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/circle_loading_view">

    //the view on top of witch the loading bar should be

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```